# pgfplots tikzpicture node to the right of axis is cut

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphics

I have a piecewise-defined function and would like a describing node to the right end of it.
Unfortunately the node is cut and not visible using this code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      axis x line=center,
      axis y line=center,
      ymin=-0.2, ymax=1.2,
    ]
          \addplot[blue,domain=-4:1] { (x<1) ? 0   : 1/0 };
          \addplot[blue,domain=1:+4] { (x>=1)? 0.5 : 1/0 } node[right] {
          $f(x) = \begin{cases}
            0   & \mbox{if } x < 1 \\
            0.5 & \mbox{if } x \geq 1
           \end{cases}$};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

How can I extend the space to the right of the axis?
The node placement should look similar to this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->] (-1,0) -- (5.5,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-3) -- (0,3.5) node[above] {$f(x)$};
\foreach \x in {-1, 0, 1, 2}
    \draw (\x cm,1pt) -- (\x cm,-3pt)
        node[anchor=north,xshift=-0.15cm] {$\x$};
\foreach \y/\ytext in {-3,-2,-1,1,2,3}
    \draw (1pt,\y cm) -- (-3pt,\y cm) node[anchor=east] {$\ytext$};
\draw[color=blue] plot[samples=100] function{log(x)} 
        node[right] {$f(x) = \log(x) $};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Great you've provided code! Can you complete it so people can copy-paste-compile?

Comment: Try `clip=false`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `clip=false` to the axis options.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,amsmath}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      axis x line=center,
      axis y line=center,
      ymin=-0.2, ymax=1.2,clip=false
    ]
          \addplot[blue,domain=-4:1] { (x<1) ? 0   : 1/0 };
          \addplot[blue,domain=1:+4] { (x>=1)? 0.5 : 1/0 } node[right] {
          $f(x) = \begin{cases}
            0   & \text{if  $x < 1$} \\
            0.5 & \text{if $x \geq 1$}
           \end{cases}$};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]